# Image View Issue with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: image, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I have a wordpress blog. In each post there are images that resides on Blogger server.
Now the problem is several of those images cannot be view on Internet Explorer 8. I do not know why, and the worst part is my client uses Internet Explorer 8 and he does not like any other browser.
  Therefore, I need all the images to be viewable in Internet Explorer 8.

Here is the link and please try to help me out: http://bit.ly/AnPTCC

P.S: When i upload an image via wordpress it shows fine.

Comment: Well i tried viewing some of your article in both IE7 and IE8 mode in IE9 and all images showed up... Is is that a particular article is not showing the images??

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro Do you see 3 images on this page ? (http://bit.ly/yKoKKM)

Comment: ok just checked it... images are NOT showing up in above link in IE8 Mode.. let e see what's the problem..

Comment: ok "flat:left" in inline css of image containing span is making image disappear in IE8... strange...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't pinpoint what was creating the problem but the override is to add height and width to the span element that contains the image.

```
<span clear: both; margin-right: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em; float: left; height: 200px; width: 135px;><img ... /></span>
```

Somehow span is getting crushed and couldn't show the image in IE8 Mode only but it works in IE7 and IE9+

Comment: @shekhar-pro I have soo many post with so many images in them. What is the fastest way of doing it ? I can not go through each post and fix images one by one.

Comment: you can try putting a small script at the end of the page to modify the style attribute of the target spans.